# Swagger how to link operation return value as authorization

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I'm writing the swagger under OAS 3.0.2 specification. And wondering if it is possible to set the authorization value (BearerAuth) through the operation return value.

Now I need to call the api/login first and then copy return token and paste to authorize panel. Is there have better way to auto link the value between operation and security?

I've tried to use [Links](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/links/), but I am not sure that support on security. (The official document do not mention the way to implement on security)

```
paths:
  /login:
    post:
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                account:
                  type: string
                password:
                  type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: data.apiToken
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                properties:
                  data:
                    type: object
                    description: data
                    properties:
                      apiToken:
                        type: string
                        description: I need this as authorization value
          links:
            ApiToken:
              operationId: apiToken
              parameters:
                apiToken: '$response.body#/data.apiToken'
```

The login was success, and response body like:

```
{
  "data":{
    "apiToken": "xxxxxx"
  }
}
```

But next step I have no idea how to do. The response is 401 because token not being sent in headers (...I'm not surprise).

```
  /someapi:
    get:
      summary: This API need auth to get data
      operationId: apiToken
      security:
        - BearerAuth: [apiToken]
      responses:
        '401':
            description: Not work
```

```
components:
  securitySchemes:
    BearerAuth:
      type: http
      scheme: bearer
      bearerFormat: JWT
```

If I copy/paste manually, it could be authorized successfully. Is there any way to solve this issue or just not support this feature right now? Thank you so much.